# Python: anonymous variable for part of the return value of a function

Tags: python

Imagine I have a Python function `foo` that returns a tuple `(a, b)`. I just want to use the second value returned, the `b`. Is there any syntax to tell python I don't want to use the first parameter? A sort of anonymous variable or something like `(~, my_var) = foo()` where the `~` would represent the syntax for the anonymous variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just unpack the tuple, use `_` for non using variables:

```
_, bValue = foo()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following syntax:

```
_, my_var = foo()
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the index and not store the first value at all:

```
def foo():
    return (1,2)

b = foo()[1]
```

Output:

```
>>> b
2
```